# Network server only sending data to client once instead of looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, stream, pickle

I'm sorry if this is a really dumb question, I'm sure someone could probably find the answer in a minute, I've just recently been getting into Python sockets.

I want my server to continually send a stream of data to my client, but for some reason, after receiving the first piece of data my client just does not receive/print out any more data.

My simplified server.py:

```
while True:
    #do some stuff with dfwebsites here
    
    senddata = True
    #time.sleep(1)
    
    #Starting the sending data part

    HEADERSIZE = 10

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((socket.gethostname(),1236))
    s.listen(5)  #queue of five
    
    while senddata==True:
        clientsocket, address = s.accept()
        print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")

        d = pd.DataFrame(dfwebsites)
        msg = pickle.dumps(d)

        #header to specify length
        #msg = "Welcome to the server!"
        msg = bytes(f'{len(msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}','utf-8')+msg    

        clientsocket.send(msg)  #type of bytes is utf-8
        #clientsocket.close()
        senddata = False
```

My client.py:

```
import socket
import pickle
import time

HEADERSIZE = 10

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1236))

while True:
    full_msg = b''
    new_msg = True
    while True:
        msg = s.recv(1024)
        if new_msg:
            print("new msg len:",msg[:HEADERSIZE])
            msglen = int(msg[:HEADERSIZE])
            new_msg = False

        print(f"full message length: {msglen}")

        full_msg += msg

        print(len(full_msg))

        if len(full_msg)-HEADERSIZE == msglen:
            print("full msg recvd")
            print(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])
            print(pickle.loads(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:]))
            new_msg = True
            full_msg = b""
```

Why can it not receive more than one peice of data?

Thank you so much for your help! I would really love even a comment telling me how to improve my qeustion!

Comment: Is that because your server only sends one piece of data? Seems a bit obvious...

Comment: Wait but it's a while loop, right? It keeps sending the dataframe dfwebsites again and again to the client?

Comment: You don't need to edit a note into the title that the question is not yet satisfactorily answered -- only after you click the checkbox next to an answer is it seen by the community as solved.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thank you for telling me!

Comment: BTW, if you look at the loop in your server, you'll see that it only does one `send()` per `accept()`, so the behavior described (that it only sends data once per incoming connection) makes sense. Maybe you want another loop that does multiple `send()`s on each socket you `accept()`ed? Also, if you want to be able to have multiple clients at the same time, I would think about spinning off a new thread per `accept()`, and having _that thread_ be responsible for your continuous `write()`s to that client.

Comment: @RebeccaBibye `accept` waits for a new connection

Comment: @user253751 so should I move accept out of the while loop?

Comment: @RebeccaBibye, or have two `while` loops, an outer one doing the `accept`s (to connect to new clients) and an inner one doing the `send`s (to send more data to the client you already have). But if you just do that naively without threading, you can only have one client at a time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy wait but I only want one client because I only want to have only one server sending data and only one client receiving a stream of data, if that makes sense? Or do I have to have multiple clients for that to work?

Comment: Okay, if that's what you want, then just two nested `while` loops (one for the `accept`s, and another inside it for the `send`s) and no threads will be fine.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you! Could you please write an answer so that I can accept it with where to put my while loops and everything? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send more than one message to each client, you need a loop *after* the `accept()` has happened.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import pickle
import pandas as pd

HEADERSIZE = 10

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(),1236))
s.listen(5)  # only one client at a time, but let up to five wait in line
    
while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")

    while senddata:
        # FIXME: refresh dfwebsites every time through this loop?
        d = pd.DataFrame(dfwebsites)
        msg = pickle.dumps(d)
        msg = bytes(f'{len(msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}','utf-8')+msg    
        try:
            clientsocket.send(msg)  #type of bytes is utf-8
        except socket.error as exc:
            print(f"Ending connection from client {address} due to {exc}")
        # FIXME: Do the below only when you want to disconnect a client
        #senddata = False
    clientsocket.close()
```